# Can Apple's New York font be used in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, fonts, ios12

Apple released the 'New York' font for iOS 13 apps, but is it allowable to use it within an iOS 12 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apple's terms tend to be [for Apple-only products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_(2019_typeface)).  There does not seem to have OS version restrictions.  You can download the font from [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/).